# logarithmic axis in hist2d

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, logarithm

I'd like to create a `plt.hist2d` plot, but with a logarithmic y-axis. I first tried `ax.set_yscale('log')` but then realized that the `hist2d` function should already be aware of the logarithmic axis to choose the bins appropriately. Is there a way to do so?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# create some bogus data
n = 10000
x = np.random.randn(n)
y = np.log(np.abs(np.random.randn(n)))
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=100)  # create a logarithmic y axis?
# plt.gca().set_yscale('log')  # doesn't work as intended
plt.show()
```

Comment: What about first setting the log scale (`plt.yscale('log')`) and then calling seaborn's 
`sns.histplot(x=x, y=y)`?